# Slow when deleting rows from an Excel table using ListRows.Item(i).Delete

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA to populate an Excel "table" range from a subset of other data.

Getting the data is fast (either from a cached array or from a SQL query on data in another sheet), but the adding and deleting is SLOW.

```
With Worksheets("Overview").ListObjects("OverviewServiceTable")

    For i = .ListRows.Count To 1 Step -1
        .ListRows(i).Delete
    Next

    For i = 0 To UBound(cache)
        Set NewRow = .ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
        NewRow.Range.Cells(1, 1).Value = cache(i)
    Next

End With
```

Using a bit of basic profiling, it's taking up to a second per row to both add and delete rows.  Is there a much faster way of clearing and updating a table like this?  Otherwise I'll resort to using "plain" cell ranges formatted to look pretty, but then nice things like the Autofilters etc will go away.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try setting calculation to manual and turn off screen updating while the code runs

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

your code here

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Perfect!  So simple.  I didn't even think of calculations :(  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but turning off calculations, screen updating, etc. didn't work for me.  After searching the web and tweaking my VBA for over an hour, here is my work-around:

```
Range("NamedTable").Clear
Range("NamedTable").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1
```

The first line clears all the rows from the table that is named "NamedTable", leaving the header row (if it exists).

The second line takes advantage of the fact that all the cells in the table are now blank, and removes all the duplicate rows (analyzing the "duplicates" in the first column)

Comment: Thank you, I, like you tried turning off all the screenupdates, calculations etc, but it still took ~1s per row, this version takes <1s for the ~5 row total

Answer (score 1):

I know, it's a bit late but..

```
listobject.DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete
```

A little help for future users ;o)

Comment: The safe version: "If Not listobject.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
    listobject.DataBodyRange.rows.Delete
End If"

Answer (score 0):

```
With Worksheets("Overview").ListObjects("OverviewServiceTable")
    Dim rng As Range
    For i = .ListRows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If rng is Nothing Then
            Set rng = .ListRows(i).DataBodyRange
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, .ListRows(i).DataBodyRange)
        End If
    Next
    rng.Delete

    For i = 0 To UBound(cache)
        Set NewRow = .ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
        NewRow.Range.Cells(1, 1).Value2 = cache(i)
    Next

End With
```

this works very well.