deleting rows via script very slow
Moving filtered rows from one worksheet to another in excel 365. I used the "Move Rows Between Tables" sample in the code editor.  My source table is 40k rows with about 40 columns. I filtered by a single column and copied 12k rows to a new table. That part is nearly instant. Those 12k rows then need removed from the source and this is where it gets very slow. (about 15min)
const sheet = sourceTable.getWorksheet();

rowAddressToRemove.reverse().forEach((address) => {
    sheet.getRange(address).delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
});

Pretty certain the slowdown is from the constant shift of data. If I sort my table by the filtered column I can manually select all the rows I need filtered out at once and delete them in a second. It’s my first time looking at excel’s API, is there a faster way to do this from a script?  Can you programmatically filter the table and select a range to delete all at once?

hmm how about filtering out the ones you need in the end instead of the ones need to remove and then replacing everything if thats possible. i dont know if what i said made sense

There's multiple things that will need filtered out in a specific order. This is just the first step I described. I was thinking about maybe adding a hidden column to flag rows for deletion and throwing that extra flag into my filter logic. Then just delete after everything else is done.

I seem to remember that actually editing the table (changing its size) is a slow operation. Doing all the changes at the end (once) sounds useful, if only so that you can compartmentalize the problem. There are a few old posts on SO with a similar problem and some solutions - here are some common ones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713035/slow-when-deleting-rows-from-an-excel-table-using-listrows-itemi-delete

I would turn screen updating off at the start of this step, and turn it on again after this step. This will provide one speed up.
Second option is to sort your rows in the macro so that the ones that you need to delete are all at the end of your data, and then select them as a range and delete them, rather than doing a for-each loop.

On reflection, the way I used to do this in vba could be the solution: which is to filter the data to show only the cells you want to delete, then use specialcells to identify the rows, then delete them. eg. filteredRange.getSpecialcells(visible).rows.delete()

Untested, but basically how I used to do it in VBA:
const sheet = sourceTable.getWorksheet();

removeRange = rowAddressToRemove.getSpecialcells(visible);
removeRange.delete();

